# structred Spark Streaming : writeStream display null dataframe

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have a task of real time processing with structred spark streaming python
so the first step was ingest csv file into kafka topic : Done

the second step was readStream from the topic kafka

```
    df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
  .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")\
  .load()
```

then I use  schema to cast my columns of my dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType() \
      .add("DriverId",IntegerType(),True) \
      .add("time",TimestampType(),True) \
      .add("Longitude",DoubleType(),True) \
      .add("Latitude",DoubleType(),True) \
      .add("SPEED",DoubleType(),True) \
      .add("EngineSpeed",IntegerType(),True) \
      .add("MAF",IntegerType(),True) \
      .add("FuelType",IntegerType(),True) \
```

the second step was to display on console what I stream juste to see if I am on the right way :

```
query1 = df\
    .writeStream\
    .format("console")\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .option("truncate", False)\
    .start()\
    .awaitTermination()
```

but the result was a dataframe withe null values
[image]

So , I have returned to schema and cast all column to stringType
the result was :

[image]

Something like a json !

**my Question is ** how can I cast right my dataframe and how to display under each column the value  and note like format json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When spark reads data from kafka, it creates a dataframe with 2 columns - key and value (These correspond to the key and value you send to kafka
- The initial data type of these 2 columns is ByteType
- You must convert them to StringType

  ```
  df = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  ```
- Then, assuming your value column is a json string, you can convert it to a struct type with the schema you have specified

  ```
  df = df.select(F.from_json(df.value,schema=my_schema).alias("value"))
  df = df.selectExpr("value.*")
  ```

More info is available [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-streaming-queries)

Comment: just when I readstream from kafka the whole correct code is         df = spark \
      .readStream \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
      .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")\
      .load() \
      .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
      .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("data")) \
      .select("data.*")

Comment: @girl_of_data Great stuff. Please accept my answer with a green tick if it worked for you. We will both earn reputation if you do :)

Comment: @ArranDuff what if my topic contains null messages, how do i skip those messages?

Comment: probably something like `df = df.filter("value is not null")`